# XeLaTeX on MiKTeX creates extra slide containing just 'T@TS1'

Tags: beamer, xetex

I compile this (admittedly very long) MWE with XeLaTeX on MiKTeX, and I see the following extra slide at the beginning of the document, which shouldn't exist:

```
% chktex-file 36
\documentclass[british,10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames},table,handout,aspectratio=169,professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[BoldFont={IBM Plex Sans Medium}]{IBM Plex Sans}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[
    arc-separator = \,,
    retain-explicit-plus,
    detect-all,
    separate-uncertainty=true,
    multi-part-units=brackets]{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[useregional,calc]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[labelfont={small,bf},font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes, shapes.misc, arrows, arrows.meta,
    calc, positioning, angles,
    decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.markings, decorations.text, calligraphy,
    pgfplots.dateplot,
    optics,
    external
}
\tikzset{>=Stealth}

\lstset{
    frame=l,
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true
}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[shape=circle, draw, minimum size=1.25em, inner sep=0pt, thick] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=}

\title{Computer Graphics}
\subtitle{Tutorial 12}
\author{SRSR333}
\date{23 August 2021}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
{\def\makelabel}
{\setlength\itemsep{\fill}\def\makelabel % separation for first level
}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\enditemize}
{\endlist}
{\endlist\ifnum\@itemdepth<2\else\vfill\fi}{}{}

\AtBeginSubsection{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \insertsubsectionhead\par
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This doesn't happen on Overleaf, which runs TeX Live 2020. Is this a MiKTeX bug? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but I ran into the same problem on MacTeX.

I found that using *any* `\usefonttheme` setting except for `serif` produced this error, but switching to `\usefonttheme{serif}` resolved the problem. It appears to be a bug and is new behavior.

For now my only solution is to compile as usual and delete the blank slide from the finished product.

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in `siunitx`, specifically, version 3. [Comments here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611502/siunitx-in-beamer-with-miktex-adds-extra-slide-containing-tts1-before-the-fir?noredirect=1#comment1529516_611502).

Comment: FTR: It doesn't happen with Tex Live 2021 for me; compiles just fine.