# siunitx v3 in beamer adds extra slide containing "T@TS1" before the first frame

Tags: beamer, miktex, siunitx

As said in the title, I started having this problem that I didn't encounter before. After some trial and error, I discovered that `siunitx` is the problem (It doesn't give problems when using the `article` class).

I use MiKTeX with TeXstudio in Windows 10.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        some text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This problem does not occur with TeX Live 2020 (tested on Overleaf).

Comment: Hi, I faced this problem too! How did you narrow it down to `siunitx` being the problem?

Comment: I just put my preamble on a simple presentation, comment all the preamble and start compiling while I uncomment the packages one by one. Using Ctrl + T and Ctrl + U in TeXstudio makes it a bit less tedious.

Comment: This seems to be bug in new version of `siunitx`. If you use old version : `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` this problem disappear.

Comment: @SRSR333 both packages work together with no problem in overleaf. May be TexLive and Miktex run different versions of siunitx.

Comment: @Zarko that solves the problem! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think overleaf have v3

Comment: Correct, v3 was only introduced in 2021 and Overleaf uses TeX Live 2020 which (probably) runs v2. I have created [an issue in the repository](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/534); let's see what Joseph has to say.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've located the issue and there will be an update to CTAN shortly. It's a simple error - I've accidentally grabbed an argument that's eating up a test.

Comment: There may be a second bug as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611591/bug-in-siunitx-introduced-revealed-by-a-recent-update.

Comment: Thank you for the fix, also in the name of Ron: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=34478