# Bug in siunitx introduced/revealed by a recent update: \micro produces unicode errors

Tags: beamer, siunitx

I have a large set of slides (in [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)) that I use for my lectures, making additions/modifications, removals for outdated information, changes in lecture boundaries, etc. each semester. After a recent update (71 packages) in TeX Live 2021 that I pulled using `tlmgr` a couple of days ago, I have started noticing that the following constructions:

```
\SI{2.3}{\micro\gram/day}
```

result in Unicode errors complaining about the `$\mu$` that is supposed to be generated. The change in [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) version is 60105 -> 60258 (from the log). I have used such constructions for years, without a problem. That suggests that either the issue is with `siunitx`, or one of the other packages that impact handling of Unicode ([`inputenc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) with the option `utf8`). I checked -- `inputenc` was not updated two days ago.

Has something changed in the packages so as to produce the effect above?

<strike>Second thing I notice: the text "T@TS1" now appears on the first slide by itself (before the titlepage). While this is annoying (without being a showstopper), I would rather find out what is causing these problems without any intervention from me.</strike>

Both these issues occurred immediately after the update -- I had not yet started making any changes to the previously correctly compiled markup. These two observations may or may not be related.

The second bug above is addressed by [siunitx v3 in beamer adds extra slide containing "T@TS1" before the first frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611502/siunitx-v3-in-beamer-adds-extra-slide-containing-tts1-before-the-first-frame). The first one -- with `\micro` resulting in Unicode errors -- is not. This is a new, yet unaddressed bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [siunitx v3 in beamer adds extra slide containing "T@TS1" before the first frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611502/siunitx-v3-in-beamer-adds-extra-slide-containing-tts1-before-the-first-frame). The package's author/maintainer has announced that he's identified the bug and that a bug fix should be available very soon.

Comment: No. It only addresses the side effect. The main bug isn't addressed by that, and I have alerted him to the existence of a second bug on that thread.

Comment: Until a bug fix for the `\micro` issue becomes available, a workaround would be to load the `siunitx` package with the option `=v2`, i.e., to run `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`.

Comment: always make a complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @Mico Note on passing multiple options: I use \usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single]{siunitx}. This is new to me, but apparently, \usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single]{siunitx}[=v2] works. I hope that this \micro issue is fixed soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the present, you can add

```latex
\DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\text{\textmu}}{-3}
```

I will need to track down exactly where the issue arises before sending an update to CTAN.

---

I have logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/535. This is basically a timing issue to do with changing the font, which interfered with detecting symbol changes. I have altered the relevant code and will update shortly.

Comment: Thanks! The workaround works for now.

Comment: @user2751530 It's doing what's supposed to happen anyway: I've just got a piece of the automation wrong