# siunitx v3 and pgfplots externalization with lualatex: \micro encoded as "ţ"

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, siunitx, tikz-external

Upgrading from TeXLive 2020 to TeXLive 2021 lead to wrong encoding of the siunitx `\micro` macro, which is displayed as "ţ". The problem only occurs in `pgfplots` figures being externalized with lualatex. While my main document is processed by `pdflatex`, only the externalized figures are being processed by `lualatex` in order to avoid memory issues.

I found two workarounds in [Bug in siunitx introduced/revealed by a recent update: \micro produces unicode errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611591/bug-in-siunitx-introduced-revealed-by-a-recent-update-micro-produces-unicode-e) :

1. loading siunitx as `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`, which suggests that the problem is introduced by siunitx v3.
2. adding `\DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\text{\textmu}}{-3}` to the header.

A MWE producing the wrong encoding is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[per-mode = symbol]{siunitx}%[=v2]
% \DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\text{\textmu}}{-3}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzexternalenable
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
    
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{external/remake next}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$c$ in $\si{\milli\meter\per\micro\second}$},
        ylabel={$v$ in \si{\milli\meter\per\micro\second}},
        ]
        \addplot[domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Given that the problem did not occur with siunitx v2, I am thinking that this is probably a bug introduced by v3. What would be the preferable solution? In general, how can I avoid this kind of issues to ensure that my document will yield the exact same output with any future version of TeXLive?

Comment: If you are using lualatex you shouldn't have either of these pacages `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (the first does nothing other than give a warning that it shouldn't be used, the second will force legacy fonts undoing luatex's default support of unicode OTF fonts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v3, I have taken a harder line than in v2 in terms of expectation of 'well-behaved' font set up. In LuaTeX, this means using a Unicode set up: either no font package (LaTeX kernel TU default) or `fontspec`. You've got `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, which is 'wrong' here.

For the case where you are using LuaTeX for plots but pdfTeX as the main engine, you'll want a selective setup

```latex
\ifdefined\directlua\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
```

More generally, updates are made to packages to fix things, and that can result in output being changed. The only certain way to address that is to not change your TeX system. However, there is a rollback mechanism in the LaTeX kernel and supported by a range of packages, including `siunitx`.

Comment: My file is processed by pdflatex, not lualatex. Only the tikz externalization runs lualatex. If I understand your answer correctly, I should avoid combining pdflatex and lualatex in this way because there is no way to setup a consistent font encoding? Thanks. @David Carlisle

Comment: @sambura See my edit

Comment: Works great! Thanks!